# APEX RESTFUL POST method

Tags: rest, oracle-apex, restful-authentication

In APEX restful service if i pick GET method with sql query all parameters go in url string. This means end-user can change parametr by himself... So  i should use POST with pl/sql block. But how can i return data from this method?
In GET i have query like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = :PARAM
```

In POST it becomes???

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = :PARAM
END;
```

I could not find anything usefull in documentstion, only about GET methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that this an old question, but I recently had the same problem and I find the solution by myself.

Maybe my solution is useful to you. I use apex in combination with [PL/JSON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/) to generate and parse JSON objects in pl/SQL. When I work with post methods in rest webservices, I do the following in the source of the resource handler:

```
declare
output json;

begin

apex_plugin_util.print_json_http_header;
output:= test_function(:INPUT_JSON_STRING);
sys.htp.p(output.to_char);

end;
```

Then, in my PL/SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function (INPUT_JSON_STRING VARCHAR2)
 RETURN JSON
IS

my_json json;

aux_string varchar2;

BEGIN

my_json :=json(INPUT_JSON_STRING);

aux_string:=my_json.get ('something').get_string;

(...)

RETURN my_json;

EXCEPTION

END test_function;
```

I've a more detailed [example](http://www.hell-desk.com/bases-datos/apex-pljson-y-web-services-restful-con-el-metodo-post/) in my blog, but it is in Spanish, sorry.

Hope this helps.